# How to professionaly answer that i don't have a work visa but that i could get one without problems if the company hires me

Tags: new-job, email, visa, new-zealand

The company is in New Zealand. I currently don't have a work permit for New Zealand but I could get one without problems after having a job offer. How to tell that to the companies when they ask me if I have a visa? I don't want to just tell them no, I would want it to sound a little more positive than that.

Comment: Why not just tell them what you said in your title?

Comment: Why are you sure you can get a Visa? Those process aren't easy. If you only requirement for a Visa were the job offer the company wouldn't worry in ask if you have a Visa they probably would tramit it for themself. That is why already having the Visa is a plus for your application.

Comment: @dwizum i want to tell them exactly that, but just use some more formal and professional English sentence

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza the New Zealand immigration website has some great info where you can input all your data and see how many points you get. With an job offer i would have almost the maximum amount of points possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we decided to use something like this.

...
thank you for your quick reply. I don't have a work permit, however, I am aware of the visa process and confident I can get one with an offer letter.
With an offer letter I would have almost the maximum amount of points possible.

Answer (score 3):

If they are going to ask you during an interview, then you can say somthing like this: "I don't have a work permit, however, I am confident I can get one with an offer letter."

It wouldn't go against you at all as you told the truth and you didn't hide any information. Also, you simply did not say "no". By telling them that you need an offer letter to apply for work permit/visa, you let them know that you are aware of the process, and that you are confident you can get it. So, that shouldn't be a problem.